# Tortoise SubWCRev.exe Pre-Build Event

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, ide, visual-studio-2005, dos

I run the following command as a pre-Build event in Visual Studio 2005 and it works fine:

```
SubWCRev.exe "C:\work\subversion\aviOffline .Net\trunk" 
"c:\test.tmpl" 
"c:\testout.txt"C:\work\subversion\aviOffline .Net\trunk"
```

So I change the command to use the in-built Visual Studio macros for better maintainability but it fails.  It appears to fail on the $(SolutionDir) macro because it appends a trailing backslash and SubWCRev.exe seems to not like the trailing backslash?

```
"SubWCRev.exe" "$(SolutionDir)" "c:\test.tmpl" "c:\testout.txt"
```

Is there a dos command or another way that removes the trailing backslash?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would try putting a trailing dot:

```
"$(SolutionDir)."
```